# Undefined is not a function... BUT... it's working in a stand alone demo file

Tags: jquery, html, function, undefined

I am trying to get this effect running: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html
Its a simple popup that's responsive and can be used to show content on demand.

1. My `<head>` includes jquery 2.0.2 and jquery-ui, they are being successfully loaded.
2. Then I include the script for the above effect:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" href="/media/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
   ```
3. Finally, just below the body ends, I include this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var options = {
           classes         : 'mm-light',
           modal           : true
       };
       options.position = 'left';
       options.zposition = 'front';
       $("#popup-1").mmenu( options ); 
       $('a.close').click(function() {
           $(this).closest( '.mm-menu' ).trigger( 'close' );
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

I am getting an **"undefined is not a function"** error for the

```
$("#popup-1").mmenu( options );
```

line...

Weirdly... when running the demo locally (without anything else on the page), it works perfectly...
so what could be going wrong in the main website version? Any leads?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Have you uploaded the file? Is the path correct? Have you included the scripts in the right order? Have you made any attempt to debug it at all? That error means that the `mmenu` script is not being included in your page correctly. Without seeing a working example of the problem, no one can tell you for certain why that is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I beg to differ - the reason the script isn't loaded is actually blindingly obvious.

Comment: @Alnitak Hmm. Think I need to check my glasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script>` tags use a `src` attribute, not `href` !

Your attempt to load the `mmenu` plugin is effectively a no-op.  Without a `src` attribute it won't even produce a 404 error, it'll look like an empty inline script.

Comment: Oh my god!! Super doofus moment!!

Let me do this and I'll report any update asap...

Comment: Working now! Can't believe such a stupid error! One more thing... the actual code to trigger the popup is:


<a href="#popup-1">popups</a>

But when the popup area is closed, the page scrolls to the top, what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: Ok, just added "return false" and all well now. :)